# Loop through array of objects and add them based on a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with objects like below.

```
0:Object
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime"
 DETAJIM1:""
 DETAJIM2:""
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z"
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137"
 KODI:"MX02"
 KODNJESIA1:"cope"
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56"
 cmimibaze:0
 gjendje:1
1:Object
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime"
 DETAJIM1:""
 DETAJIM2:""
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z"
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137"
 KODI:"MX02"
 KODNJESIA1:"cope"
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56"
 cmimibaze:0
 gjendje:1
2:Object
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime"
 DETAJIM1:""
 DETAJIM2:""
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z"
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137"
 KODI:"MX03"
 KODNJESIA1:"cope"
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56"
 cmimibaze:0
 gjendje:1
3:Object
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime"
 DETAJIM1:""
 DETAJIM2:""
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z"
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13141"
 KODI:"MX02"
 KODNJESIA1:"cope"
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56"
 cmimibaze:0
 gjendje:1
```

Now I want to remove the duplicates using these 2 properties: `"KODI"` and `"KODARTIKULLI"`, for example at the first 2 objects you can see that both `"KODI"` and `"KODARTIKULLI"` are the same so I want to keep only one.

And the second question which is more important and may even solve the first one. These objects are products that are taken from different storage units, ("KODI" represents the storage unit id). So what I want is for a unique product (product id is "KODARTIKULLI") to add all the available units (available units are stored in "gjendje"). This may seem a bit complicated but i want that the above array to look like below:

```
0:Object
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime"
 DETAJIM1:""
 DETAJIM2:""
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z"
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137"
 KODI:"MX02"
 KODNJESIA1:"cope"
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56"
 cmimibaze:0
 gjendje:2
1:Object
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime"
 DETAJIM1:""
 DETAJIM2:""
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z"
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13141"
 KODI:"MX02"
 KODNJESIA1:"cope"
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56"
 cmimibaze:0
 gjendje:1
```

So since the first 2 objects are the same product and come from the same storage unit, to just keep one. And the second and third objects are still the same product but come from different storage units, so in this case just add `"gjendje"`. In the end there should be just one product with `KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137"`and `"gjendje:2"` (`gjendje:1+gjendje:1=gjendje:2`). The same for products with different `"KODARTIKULLI"`.

**What I've tried:**
I can remove duplicates based on one property but not using 2 properties:

```
// Remove duplicates of it's own, ex: only keeps one unique object based on KODARTIKULL
function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
     var newArray = [];
     var lookupObject  = {};

     for(var i in originalArray) {
        lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
     }

     for(i in lookupObject) {
         newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
     }
      return newArray;
 }
```

I can call this twice for both `"KODARTIKULLI"` and `"KODI"` but that won't work because it will just keep removing products not based on my conditions.

I also tried to add `"gjendje"` by looping through the whole array. So for each product I'll add the `"gjendje"` from all the other products with the same `"KODARTIKULLI"`. After this then I'd call the above function and since all the same products would have the same `"gjendje"`, I'd just remove all the duplicates. But this also doesn't work because there are some products that come from the same storage unit which need to just be removed because are exactly the same.

```
  // Loop through all objects in the array
  for (var i = 0; i < newArrMagGjendje.length; i++) {

    // Loop through all of the objects beyond i
    // Don't increment automatically; we will do this later
    for (var j = i+1; j < newArrMagGjendje.length;j++ ) {

      // Check if our x values are a match
      if (newArrMagGjendje[i].KODARTIKULLI == newArrMagGjendje[j].KODARTIKULLI) {
        newArrMagGjendje[i].gjendje=newArrMagGjendje[i].gjendje+newArrMagGjendje[j].gjendje;
        newArrayM.push( newArrMagGjendje[i]);
      } 
    }
  }
```

I know it looks a bit long, but I'm stuck at the moment and didn't know how to explain it differently. 
Thank you

Comment: You might want to split the question in smaller pieces to make it easier for people to understand the context and the implications.

Comment: What you mean by storage unit here

Comment: @Krishjs The physical products are stored in different buildings that have unique id like MX01 or MX02. So for each product exists a record on different storage buildings (or storage units) and I want to add them all together, removing duplicate records from the same storage unit.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicates(arr) {
    console.log("original length: "+arr.length);
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var listI = arr[i];
        loopJ: for (var j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            var listJ = arr[j];
            if (listI === listJ) continue; //Ignore itself
            for (var k=listJ.length; k>=0; k--) {
                if (JSON.stringify(listJ[k]) !== JSON.stringify(listI[k])) continue loopJ;
            }// At this point, their values are equal.

            arr.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log("length without duplicates: "+arr.length);
    return arr;
}
```

This is a function I wrote a little while back to remove any duplicate objects in an array. Since you want to apply only to two attributes then all we need to do is remove the 3rd loop and just check those two attributes instead.

Also note, there are better ways to compare objects than JSON.stringify but efficiency wasn't needed for me, I don't know if that's the case for you.

Modified code for your purposes:

```
function removeDuplicates(arr) {
    console.log("original length: "+arr.length);
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var listI = arr[i];
        loopJ: for (var j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            var listJ = arr[j];
            if (listI === listJ) continue; //Ignore itself
            if (JSON.stringify(listJ.KODI) !== JSON.stringify(listI.KODI)) {
                continue loopJ;
            }
            if (JSON.stringify(listJ.KODNJESIA1) !== JSON.stringify(listI.KODNJESIA1)) {
                continue loopJ;
            }      
            arr.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log("length without duplicates: "+arr.length);
    return arr;
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to filter based on 2 properties is to create a temporary hash object that uses the combined values of those 2 properties as keys.

```js
var data = [{
  key1: 'A',
  key2: 1
}, {
  key1: 'A',
  key2: 1
}, {
  key1: 'B',
  key2: 1
}];
var tmp = {};

var res = data.filter(function(item) {
  // use a separator for the values to prevent possible collisions and prevent adding numbers 
  var combined = item.key1 + '|' +  item.key2,
     isUnique = !tmp[combined];
  if (isUnique) {
    tmp[combined] = true;    
  }  
  return isUnique;

});

console.log(res)
```

The second part of the question is a bit unclear

Comment: For the second part of the question: Each storage unit may have different quantities for the same product. So what I want to do, is add all the quantities from different storage units into one. After removing all duplicates from the same storage unit (as you suggest above), I need to add the quantities of products that have the same `KODARTIKULLI`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b), that will allow you to apply a callback function to your array to output a new array matching the functions output criteria.

As an aside, please read up on how to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you have an array of objects it helps to have an actual array of objects and not a string that needs to be converted in order to create a working example.

#### Edit

Added a second reducer to total the gjendje key on matched Kodartikulli keys, you could do this with one reducer, but (*personal opinion*) I think it is generally a better practice to keep your functions narrow in scope.

```js
const data = [
  {
    BARKOD:"Pa Detatime",
    DETAJIM1:"",
    DETAJIM2:"",
    DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
    KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137",
    KODI:"MX02",
    KODNJESIA1:"cope",
    PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
    cmimibaze:0,
    gjendje:1,
  },
  {
    BARKOD:"Pa Detatime",
    DETAJIM1:"",
    DETAJIM2:"",
    DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
    KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137",
    KODI:"MX02",
    KODNJESIA1:"cope",
    PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
    cmimibaze:0,
    gjendje:1,
  },
  {
    BARKOD:"Pa Detatime",
    DETAJIM1:"",
    DETAJIM2:"",
    DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
    KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137",
    KODI:"MX03",
    KODNJESIA1:"cope",
    PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
    cmimibaze:0,
    gjendje:1,
  },
  {
    BARKOD:"Pa Detatime",
    DETAJIM1:"",
    DETAJIM2:"",
    DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
    KODARTIKULLI:"SD13141",
    KODI:"MX02",
    KODNJESIA1:"cope",
    PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
    cmimibaze:0,
    gjendje:1,
  }
];

const dedupe = (group, current) => {
  const index = group.findIndex(val => (val.KODI == current.KODI && val.KODARTIKULLI == current.KODARTIKULLI));
  if (index === -1) {
    group.push(current);
  }
  return group;
};
const totals = (group, current) => {
  const index = group.findIndex(val => val.KODARTIKULLI == current.KODARTIKULLI);
  if (index === -1) {
    return [ ...group, current];
  }

  group[index].gjendje += current.gjendje;
  return group;
};

const result = data.reduce(dedupe, []).reduce(totals, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @D Lowther, thank you that works for the first part of the question. Do you have any idea how to solve the second one? At the output of your script above, you can see that the first 2 objects have the same `KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137"`. How can I add the `"gjendje"` (quantity in english) property of all those objects that have the same `KODARTIKULLI` and just keep one object with the total of quantities for each unique  `KODARTIKULLI` ?

Comment: @Alfred You would just use another reducer to make a comparison and return the reduced object array. *Example added to answer*

Answer (score 0):

First get unique record based on KODARTIKULLI and add the storage units to that unique record.

```
var array = [{
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime",
 DETAJIM1:"",
 DETAJIM2:"",
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137",
 KODI:"MX02",
 KODNJESIA1:"cope",
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
 cmimibaze:0,
 gjendje:1,
 },{
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime",
 DETAJIM1:"",
 DETAJIM2:"",
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137",
 KODI:"MX02",
 KODNJESIA1:"cope",
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
 cmimibaze:0,
 gjendje:1
 },{
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime",
 DETAJIM1:"",
 DETAJIM2:"",
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13137",
 KODI:"MX03",
 KODNJESIA1:"cope",
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
 cmimibaze:0,
 gjendje:1
 },
 {
 BARKOD:"Pa Detatime",
 DETAJIM1:"",
 DETAJIM2:"",
 DTMODIFIKIM:"2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
 KODARTIKULLI:"SD13141",
 KODI:"MX02",
 KODNJESIA1:"cope",
 PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI:"Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
 cmimibaze:0,
 gjendje:1
}];
```

Here added new property to storage all the KODI info as array

```
function addStorage(arr,hash,index,sd){
 var item = hash[index];
  if(item.SD.indexOf(sd) === -1){
    item.SD.push(sd);
  }
  arr[item.index].StorageUnit = item.SD;
  arr[item.index].gjendje = item.SD.length;
}
```

getUnique method will remove the duplicate based on KODARTIKULLI and add record with different store to unique record

```
function getUnique(arr) {
  var hash = [];
  var storageHash = [];
  var length = arr.length,index = 0;
  for (; index < length;) {
    var item = arr[index];
    var key = item.KODARTIKULLI;    
    if (hash[key] !== undefined)
    {      
      addStorage(arr,hash,key,item.KODI);
      arr.splice(index, 1);
      index--;
      length--;
    } else {      
      hash[key] = {
         index:index,
         SD:[item.KODI]
      }
    }
    index++;
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(getUnique(array));
```