# Loop through array of objects and add objects that have the same id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects as below and I want to add the quantity of those objects whose product_id is the same.

```
[
      {
        "BARKOD": "Pa Detatime",
        "DETAJIM1": "",
        "DETAJIM2": "",
        "DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
        "product_id": "SD13137",
        "KODI": "MX02",
        "KODNJESIA1": "cope",
        "PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
        "cmimibaze": 0,
        "quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "BARKOD": "Pa Detatime",
        "DETAJIM1": "",
        "DETAJIM2": "",
        "DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
        "product_id": "SD13137",
        "KODI": "MX03",
        "KODNJESIA1": "cope",
        "PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
        "cmimibaze": 0,
        "quantity": 3
      },
      {
        "BARKOD": "Pa Detatime",
        "DETAJIM1": "",
        "DETAJIM2": "",
        "DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
        "product_id": "SD13141",
        "KODI": "MX02",
        "KODNJESIA1": "cope",
        "PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
        "cmimibaze": 0,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
```

So the end array should be like below:

```
[
      {
        "BARKOD": "Pa Detatime",
        "DETAJIM1": "",
        "DETAJIM2": "",
        "DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
        "product_id": "SD13137",
        "KODI": "MX02",
        "KODNJESIA1": "cope",
        "PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
        "cmimibaze": 0,
        "quantity": 4
      },
      {
        "BARKOD": "Pa Detatime",
        "DETAJIM1": "",
        "DETAJIM2": "",
        "DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z",
        "product_id": "SD13141",
        "KODI": "MX02",
        "KODNJESIA1": "cope",
        "PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56",
        "cmimibaze": 0,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
```

I asked this question along with another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054217/loop-through-array-of-objects-and-add-them-based-on-a-property/47055308#47055308) but was able to solve only the other question. If anyone might solve I'd be very grateful.
Thank you.

Comment: But the "KODI" property in object 1 and object 2 are MX02 and MX03 respectively. are you sure you want to merge the two objects?

Comment: @darthaditya Yes, that part is not important, you may leave it as MX02 or MX03, doesn't matter.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research. [Search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO. Attempt to do the work. **If** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reduce, like this:

```js
let input = [{"BARKOD": "Pa Detatime","DETAJIM1": "","ETAJIM2": "","DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z","product_id": "SD13137","KODI": "MX02","KODNJESIA1": "cope","PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56","cmimibaze": 0,"quantity": 1},{"BARKOD": "Pa Detatime","DETAJIM1": "","DETAJIM2": "","DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z","product_id": "SD13137","KODI": "MX03","KODNJESIA1": "cope","PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56","cmimibaze": 0,"quantity": 3},{"BARKOD": "Pa Detatime","DETAJIM1": "","DETAJIM2": "","DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z","product_id": "SD13141","KODI": "MX02","KODNJESIA1": "cope","PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56","cmimibaze": 0,"quantity": 1}];

let output = input.reduce(function(res, el) {
  if(res[el.product_id]) {
    res[el.product_id].quantity += el.quantity;
  } else {
    res[el.product_id] = el;
  }
  return res;
}, {});

let outputArr = Object.values(output);

console.log(outputArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{"BARKOD": "Pa Detatime", "DETAJIM1": "", "DETAJIM2": "", "DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z", "product_id": "SD13137", "KODI": "MX02", "KODNJESIA1": "cope", "PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56", "cmimibaze": 0, "quantity": 1 }, {"BARKOD": "Pa Detatime", "DETAJIM1": "", "DETAJIM2": "", "DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z", "product_id": "SD13137", "KODI": "MX03", "KODNJESIA1": "cope", "PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56", "cmimibaze": 0, "quantity": 3 }, {"BARKOD": "Pa Detatime", "DETAJIM1": "", "DETAJIM2": "", "DTMODIFIKIM": "2017-10-02T16:06:53.206Z", "product_id": "SD13141", "KODI": "MX02", "KODNJESIA1": "cope", "PERSHKRIMARTIKULLI": "Emporio Armani 4097 5574 71 56", "cmimibaze": 0, "quantity": 1 } ]
 var mapObj = {};
 for(var a of data){
    if(mapObj[a["product_id"]]== undefined)
      mapObj[a["product_id"]] = 0;
    mapObj[a["product_id"]] += a["quantity"]
 }
var data2 = [];
for(var a of data){
  if(mapObj[a["product_id"]] == undefined)
     continue;
  a["quantity"] = mapObj[a["product_id"]];
  data2.push(a)
  delete mapObj[a["product_id"]];
}
console.log(data2)
```